# Trying to create a ban button in Laravel. Don't get any error just get not found - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

here is my controller method

```php
public function blockUser(User $user)
{
    
    $user = User::findOrFail($user->id);
    $user->blocked_at = Carbon::now();
    $user->save();

    return Redirect()->route('admin.users.index')->with('User has been blocked');
    
}
```

This is my web.php

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'adminView'])->name('admin.view');
    Route::get('/admin/users', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.users.index');
    Route::delete('/admin/users/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'adminDelete'])->name('admin.users.destroy');
    Route::get('/admin/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.posts.index');
    Route::put('/admin/users/{users}', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'blockUser'])->name('admin.users.ban');
});
```

This is my blade

```html
 <td>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('ban-user-from-{{ $user->id }}').submit()">
    <i class="fas fa-ban" title="Ban"></i>
    </button>

    <form id="ban-user-from-{{ $user->id }}" action="{{ route('admin.users.ban', [$user->id]) }}" method="POST" style="display: none">
        @csrf 
        @method("PUT")
    </form>
</td>
```

I have a blocked_at column in my database and have done the functionality on the middleware and kernel.  If I add today date manually into the database for that field the user is blocked and a message comes up when they try to login.  However I am now trying to create a button for the admin panel so that an admin can just block a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller :

```
public function blockUser(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->users);
    $user->blocked_at = Carbon::now();
    $user->save();

    return Redirect()->route('admin.users.index')->with('User has been blocked');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Why discourage route model binding?

Comment: @miken32 needs a lot of changes, so I edited my answer with this easy method